# Freeform (Pro) and Multiple Site Manager

Tags: templates, multi-site-manager, solspace-freeform

I just dropped my Freeform (Pro) form code into a template in a second site running on Multiple Site Manager. It's not rendering, and a peek in the Control Panel for site #2 shows no fields or forms.

This form is a duplicate of one set up for the main site, so I'm happy to see the submissions reside there, and for it to follow the settings there.

Is it possible to leverage the default site's Freeform setup? Or do I need to reproduce this in site #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this Solspace Support Forum post](http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/14448/) covers duplicating a form in your second site.